# C# get values separated by commas (,) and en dash (-) in the multi-lined Textbox and insert them into multiple rows and columns in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, textbox

I am implementing a software to save books. So I want to add many authors and theirs roles to a book. So i'm Typing author name and his role separated with a (-) en hash and I add many authors to one book by using (,) in the textbox.
Look at this image for more info.
**Image :- [Adding a new book to the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o5MV.png)**
***My Book Table***

```
RecordID| BookID  | Book Name        | ISBN     |
---------------------------------------------------
001     |125      |Journey of my life|0123456789|
```

***My Author Table***

```
RecordID| AuthorID| Author Name
---------------------------------
001     |005      |B.A. Lakshan Enosh  
002     |006      |John williams  
003     |007      |graham winter  
004     |008      |Dilshan nim
```

***Book_Author Table***

```
RecordID| BookID  | AuthorID| ROLE|  
---------------------------------  
001     |125      |005      |Author|  
002     |125      |006      |Author|  
003     |125      |007      |Editor|  
004     |125      |008      |Editor|
```

i need to insert values to my many to many relationship table in the database like above.

My question - How can i separate data in the textbox and insert them to the my many to many table.

**(Please Refer the picture I have attached before giving me bad comments) Thank you**

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you ever heard of google? ther are **billions** of hits if you just tip _c# string split by comma_ ...

Comment: I tried many. But i couldn't do both the things (Separating name and role by (-) and  separate names by (,)). This is not all about splitting. This has to take multiple names with its role from a single multi-lined textbox.

Comment: Why are you not using multiple textboxes?

Comment: Did you check my photo? I can't exactly say how many authors are there for one book. There can be one author or 20 authors and editors for one book. you are asking me to add 20 textboxes for names and 20 textboxes for roles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your picture, the format is like:

> name1 - role1, name2 - role2, name3 - role3

Please try below to split into each pair of name and role.

```
string strAuthorRole = txtAuthorRole.Text;
string[] lstAuthorRole = strAuthorRole.Split(',');
string[] lstAuthor = new string[lstAuthorRole.Length];
string[] lstRole = new string[lstAuthorRole.Length];
string strMsg = "";

for (int i = 0; i < lstAuthorRole.Length; i++)
{
    string[] pair = lstAuthorRole[i].Split('-');
    lstAuthor[i] = pair[0].Trim();
    lstRole[i] = pair[1].Trim();
    // sample output
    strMsg += lstAuthor[i] + " (" + lstRole[i] + ")\n";
}

MessageBox.Show(strMsg);
```

By using lstAuthor and lstRole, you can then insert each pair (having same index in the arrays) into your table. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Linn. This is what i wanted. Let me try this in my code. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

if I understood it correctly then your text format is like

> name of author - role1, role2, role3

This can be seperate out in two steps

step 1. Separate author and roles.

Step 2. Separate roles into multiple separate roles

Here is the code. Try it out

```
        string[] authorRoles = yourString.Split('-');
        string[] roles = authorRoles[1].Split(',');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer prasad.. This is not actually i wanted

I want something like this

authorName1 - Role1 , author Name2 - Role2 , authorName3 - Role 3

Comment: @EnoshShan I guess you upvoted my answer. As per your comments on both the answers and your question, It seems that **linn Htet** suggested you exact or more accurate answer.